# Define Column based off of 3 columns in another dataset - simple example works, but more complex errors

Tags: r

I want to define a column in Dataframe A based off of a column in a Dataframe B, after filtering based on 2 different columns in Dataframe B. I can get this to work in a simple example but get an error when doing it in the actual df.

Reproducible example:

```
> repro
  pid    a1     a2
1 101  blue spring
2 102  rasp summer
3 103 black   fall
4 104  cran spring
5 105  goji summer
> ex <- data.frame(pid=c(101, 107, 109, 102, 105))
> ex
  pid
1 101
2 107
3 109
4 102
5 105

> ex %>% mutate(berry=case_when(pid==repro$pid & repro$a2 %in% c("spring", "summer") ~ repro$a1))
  pid berry
1 101  blue
2 107  <NA>
3 109  <NA>
4 102  <NA>
5 105  goji
```

However, when I use the same syntax in mutate in the larger more complicated dataframe, I get this error:
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `cta_anyca = case_when(...)`.
✖ `cta_anyca` must be size 1, not 14457.

What do I have to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `==` (which is elementwise) do a join and then replace.  If we check the order of `pid` in both datasets, it is evident that the '102' is not picked up as `==` does comparison on each corresponding element (assuming both datasets have the same number of rows)

```
library(dplyr)
ex %>%
   left_join(repro) %>%
    mutate(berry = case_when(a2 %in% c("spring", "summer") ~ a1), 
       .keep = "unused")
```

-output

```
  pid berry
1 101  blue
2 107  <NA>
3 109  <NA>
4 102  rasp
5 105  goji
```

#### data

```
repro <- structure(list(pid = 101:105, a1 = c("blue", "rasp", "black", 
"cran", "goji"), a2 = c("spring", "summer", "fall", "spring", 
"summer")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5"))
```